# Multiple Source Control Navigator Branch Shown of same project Xcode 9.2

Tags: xcode, version-control, xcode9.2

Here in Xcode 9.2, I see inside Source Control Navigator multiple branch of same project as shown

[image]

How to remove the other which is old.